# Authorize requests to app engine app with a service account

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using the `app.yaml`'s `login: admin` in `handlers` to restrict access to my app only to selected Google accounts (which I can edit in IAM). I'm using the `python27` standard environment on GAE.

I would like to use the JSON API my app exposes from another server app (not hosted on GAE). Using a service account looks like a straightforward solution, but I am unable to get the scopes or the request itself right, so the endpoint would see an authenticated Google user.

The `service-user` currently has `Project/Viewer` role in the IAM. I tried a few more like `AppEngine/Viewer`, `AppEngine/Admin`. I also tried some more scopes.

My test code:

```
"""Try do do an API request to a deployed app
with the current service account.

https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html
"""
import sys

from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
from google.oauth2 import service_account

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        sys.exit("use: %s url" % sys.argv[0])

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        'service-user.json')
    scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only'])
    authed_http = AuthorizedSession(scoped_credentials)

    response = authed_http.request('GET', sys.argv[1])

    print response.status_code, response.reason
    print response.text.encode('utf-8')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There is no error, the request behaves like unauthenticated. I checked the headers on the server, and while requesting from the browser there are several `session` cookies, the `AuthorizedSession` request contains single `Authorization: Bearer ..` header.

Comment: What error(s) do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the roles you would need is [App Engine Admin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control#predefined_roles_comparison_matrix); it's designed for this purpose. It should also work with the [viewer/editor/owner primitive roles](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/users/adminusers). That being said, to make sure it's not a "role" issue, simply give it the project owner role and also the explicit App Engine Admin role and try again. This will eliminate any role-based issue.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: There is no error. The request is considered (completely) unauthenticated by the server.

Comment: Did you try use "Project Owner" and "App Engine Admin" roles? You may also check step by step [App Engine Authentication Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/authenticate-users)